# Ubuntu 22.04.3 “ACP BIOS Error (bug) Couldn’t resolve symbol error on Asus X513EP

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04, flicker

After updating the kernal 6.2.0-generic. I’ll update the exact version later. That causes so much problem for me. When ubuntu bootup(before login screen) its flickering three times. Also bootup is too slow than previous kernal version(5.15 something). Please help me to solve this issue.

Also I’m having dual bootup with win11

This BIOS error came up when i power off the Ubuntu

[ACP Bios error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7zUy.jpg)